# Matlab function with vector output return whole vector

Tags: matlab, vector

Perhaps it is very basic but I could not find an answer.

I have a function that outputs a vector. For instance, if you do

```
[c1 c2 c3] = quat2angle(a)
```

but if you do

```
quat2angle(a)
```

then it only outputs `c1`. I want to do `[1 2 3]'- quat2angle(a)` but then it subtracts only `c1`.

Is there a way to get a vector out?

Comment: I am not sure if there's a way to explicitly specify `nargout`. However, you could assign to `[c1 c2 c3]` and then subtract that from `[1 2 3]'`?

Comment: This is standard function behavior. Note that in the first case, it does NOT return a vector, but assigns the output to 3 separate variables. This is always true when on the **LHS** square brackets `[ ]` are used. You have misplaced your expectations. There at least two ways around it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define a wrapper function like this and use that instead of the original function

```
function c = quat2angle_w(a)
[c1 c2 c3] = quat2angle(a);
c = [c1 c2 c3];
end
```

Answer (score 3):

If the function is your own or you can modify it you could do something like this using [`varargout`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/varargout.html) and [`nargout`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/nargout.html):

```
function varargout=quat2angle(a)
% Create example output for demo
c1 = a;
c2 = 2*a.^2;
c3 = 3*a;
% Switch output format based on how many output arguments user specified
if nargout <= 1
    varargout{1} = [c1;c2;c3];
else
    varargout{1} = c1;
    varargout{2} = c2;
    if nargout > 2
        varargout{3} = c3;
    end
end
```

The use of `varargout` isn't entirely necessary as you could simply choose to return `c1 = [c1;c2;c3];` if `nargout <= 1`. But for more complex situations this is the sort of thing you'd do.

If the function can't be modified then you no other choice than

```
[c1,c2,c3] = quat2angle(a);
[1 2 3]' - [c1;c2;c3]
```

Comment: It is a build in function so it can't by easily modified. But thanks anyway!